# jQuery timeago plugin not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, timeago

I am using jQuery timeago plugin, and it is working in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. The usage is pretty simple as given on the website.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
    });
```

> `<abbr class="timeago" title="{{ISO8601_TIME timeStamp}}">{{COMMENT_DATE_TIME timeStamp}}</abbr>`

The title and the date in the `<abbr>` tags is the iso timestamp. It works as expected in Chrome and Firefox but simply prints out the timestamp in Safari (e.g 2012-11-28 19:16:49).

Can anyone please help me out where the problem is?

**EDIT**
In Chrome:
[image]

In Safari:
[image]

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of when it goes wrong?

Comment: @Jack I have uploaded the screenshots in both chrome and safari. Plz see.

Comment: That doesn't help much; we would need a reproducible case to work with; try to make it reproduce on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

for utc string created from: newDate.toUTCString():

in Google Chrome browser,  calling jQuery.timeago('Fri, 31 May 2013 10:37:16 GMT') produce output 'NaN years ago'. However, it is working fine in Firefox browse.

The best is to use newDate.toISOString() and it works in both browser.